# Spy click event on element in jasmine

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I have file app.js:

```
var container = $('.feed'),
feedList = $('.feed-list');
...

feedList.on('click', 'a', function() {
var item = $(this);
$('body').addClass('menu-hidden');
loadFeed(item.data('id'));
return false;}
...
```

hiperlink element have class: ".feed-list"

I've tried to sure about click events and that menu is hidden. 
And my spec is:

```
it('Checking toggle on menu through spies function', function() {
var feedList = $('.feed-list');
spyOn(feedList, 'on');
feedList.trigger('click');
expect(feedList.On).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect($('body').hasClass('menu-hidden')).toBe(true);
});
```

So...test is fail. It complain something about feedList object... "not defined".

I hope to your help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you need to define your variable `feedList` . Change your line `feedList = $('.feed-list');`  to `var feedList = $('.feed-list');`

Comment: Thanks! I did, but: **_Expected a spy, but got undefined._**  (((